# After taking image using react-native-image-picker but Failed to submit via Laravel API

Tags: javascript, laravel, react-native, api

I have a react-native app where I used react-native-image-picker to take image from gallery and it successfully taken and preview on image tag. But failed to submit the image on laravel API.

- Node version: 16.13.2
- npm version: 8.1.2
- react-native-cli version: 2.0.1
- react-native version: 0.66.1

**react-native code for image-pick is given below:**

```
       `<TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.fileInput}
          onPress={() => {
            let options = {
              storageOptions: {
                  path: 'images',
              },
            };
            launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);
        
            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
                alert(response.customButton);
            } else {

                setDocument(response.assets[0].uri)              
                setFromImage({
                  uri: response.assets[0].uri,
                  type: response.assets[0].type,
                  name: response.assets[0].fileName,
                  // data: response.data
                  data: response.assets[0].uri
                })

                console.log(fromImage);

            }
            });
          }}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#00549F', fontSize: 16,fontWeight: 'bold',}}>
          <Icon name='file' type='font-awesome' color='#00549F' /> Choose File
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>`
```

**react-native code for Laravel API submit is given below:**

`<TouchableOpacity
style={styles.button}
onPress={() => {

```
    const url = appUrl.testImageStore;

    const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        document: fromImage,
      }),
    };
   
    fetch(url, config)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        // console.log(responseJson)
        if (responseJson.status == '2') {
          Alert.alert(responseJson.message);
        } else if (responseJson.status == '1') {
          Alert.alert(responseJson.message);
          // navigation.navigate('Home');
        } else if (responseJson.status == '0') {
          Alert.alert(responseJson.message);
        // } else if (responseJson.status == '3') {
        //   setErrorMessages(responseJson.messages.toArray())
        // Alert.alert(responseJson.messages);

        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        //Alert.alert("Failed to registration 2");
      });

  }}>
  <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'white', fontSize: 16}}>
    Submit
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>`
```

**Laravel API code is given below:**

```
     `public function testImageStore(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('document')){
            $image             = $request->file('document');
            $folder_path       = 'uploads/images/documents/';
            $image_new_name    = Str::random(20).'-'.now()->timestamp.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //resize and save to server
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($folder_path.$image_new_name);
            return response()->json([
                "message"=>"file found & stored",
                "status"=>"1",
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([`enter code here`
            "message"=>"file not found",
            "status"=>"1",
        ]);

    }`
```

After submitting image it don't found and the output screen is given attached file, please concern there.

[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWuqx.jpg) to see the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-native-image-picker` returns image URI reference to the device media storage not actually image data.

You have 2 options to get real image data:

1. Set  `includeBase64` property to `true` and upload `base64` image data
2. Fetch image data as BLOB format and upload BLOB data

```
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onload = function () {
   resolve(xhr.response);
 };
 xhr.onerror = function (e) {
   reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
 };
 xhr.responseType = "blob";
 xhr.open("GET", localPath, true);
 xhr.send(null);
});

// Code to upload to BLOB data to the server here 

// We're done with the blob, close and release it
blob.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel. It was helpful for me.

Comment: Great, Glad to hear that